# Why does this RewriteRule work with [R] but not with [QSA,L]?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a very simple RewriteRule but I cannot figure out why it does not want to work. Perhaps its just exhaustion talking, but something seems wonky.

I want to redirect a url that looks like `http://mydomain.com/abc` to `http://mydomain.com/abc/index.php/xyz`, but I do not want the URL to change.

Here is my .htaccess in its entirety:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /abc/

#redirect the homepage 
RewriteRule ^$  index.php/msj [QSA,L]
```

When I do that, I get "No input file specified.". If I change the [QSA,L] to [R] it works, but it actually redirects the URL.

What am I misunderstanding?

EDIT: output of $_SERVER

```
array(34) { [
"PATH"]=> string(29) "/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin" [
"RAILS_ENV"]=> string(10) "production" [
"FCGI_ROLE"]=> string(9) "RESPONDER" [
"UNIQUE_ID"]=> string(24) "UxDcvK3suH0AABgWvXUAAAAj" [
"SCRIPT_URL"]=> string(1) "/" [
"SCRIPT_URI"]=> string(22) "http://themspress.org/" [
"dsid"]=> string(8) "25793844" [
"ds_id_25793844"]=> string(0) "" [
"DH_USER"]=> string(13) "juancommander" [
"HTTP_HOST"]=> string(14) "themspress.org" [
"HTTP_CONNECTION"]=> string(5) "close" [
"HTTP_ACCEPT"]=> string(74) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" [
"HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=> string(120) "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36" [
"HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=> string(17) "gzip,deflate,sdch" [
"HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=> string(23) "en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6" [
"HTTP_COOKIE"]=> string(190) "OJSSID=Siy7xdofJurGtBcNUk1880; __utma=154159997.1153519437.1393351515.1393522373.1393598726.4; __utmc=154159997; __utmz=154159997.1393351515.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)" [
"SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=> string(0) "" [
"SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=> string(6) "Apache" [
"SERVER_NAME"]=> string(14) "themspress.org" [
"SERVER_ADDR"]=> string(15) "173.236.187.201" [
"SERVER_PORT"]=> string(2) "80" [
"REMOTE_ADDR"]=> string(14) "189.138.120.63" [
"DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(51) "/home/juancommander/themspress.org/var/www/html/ojs" [
"SERVER_ADMIN"]=> string(24) "webmaster@themspress.org" [
"SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=> string(61) "/home/juancommander/themspress.org/var/www/html/ojs/index.php" [
"REMOTE_PORT"]=> string(5) "53719" [
"GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=> string(7) "CGI/1.1" [
"SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=> string(8) "HTTP/1.1" [
"REQUEST_METHOD"]=> string(3) "GET" [
"QUERY_STRING"]=> string(0) "" [
"REQUEST_URI"]=> string(1) "/" [
"SCRIPT_NAME"]=> string(10) "/index.php" [
"PHP_SELF"]=> string(10) "/index.php" [
"REQUEST_TIME"]=> int(1393614012) }
```

Comment: Is this CI or some other framework?

Comment: its Open Journal Systems. It uses PHP. I actually have another install on another server that has the same setup (although, obviously not exactly the same) and its working there...

Comment: Is abc a real directory? and what directory is your htaccess file located?

Comment: If you want to pass through to the php handler, you might need to use the [`PT` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt) on the `RewriteRule`.

Comment: abc is a real directory, and the .htaccess file is inside that directory.

Comment: and the PT flag gives the same problem (using just [PT])

Comment: Can you double check the values of AllowPathInfo  on the two systems, then try the [DPI] flag?  It doesn't small like a match match for DPI, but your problem is definitely in the same neighborhood.  The rewritelog would probably give a pretty good hint too.

Comment: @mrjink: the PT flag does not help

Comment: @covener: DPI flag does not help either

Comment: Does the rule work when you append the / to the URL, i.e. `http://my domain.com/abc/ v.s. http://my domain.com/abc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the source of the problem in the [Dreamhost documentation](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Mod_rewrite).

It seems that:

> The FastCGI version when paired with Apache 2.2 doesn't seem to like
>   the rewriterule index.php/$1. Instead it prefers index.php?$1 but some
>   CMS don't like that.

The CMS I am using does not like that. So undone's comment to use ?$1 was on the right track, but because I had no explanation, and the CMS I am using (Open Journal Systems) does not work with the pathinfo stuff after a ?, then it was just not working.

The solution was to change from FastCGI to just regular CGI.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happens:

You send a request for `http://mydomain.com/abc`. Apache's `mod_rewrite`  rewrites the URL to `http://mydomain.com/abc/index.php/msj`  but the first URI is kept. so when Apache asks php to handle the request, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`  will be `/abc/`  not `/abc/index.php/msj`  and since your php application (OJS) is using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`  to handle the request, it won't know about the rewrite applied to you URL. When you replace `[QSA,L]`  with `[R]`, apache sends a `Location` header to your browser. Your browser sends another request that actually changes the  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` .

Unfortunately, there is no way **that I know** to rewrite that part.

---

**Update**:
Put this in your `.htaccess`  file and check if whether it works or not?

```
AcceptPathInfo On
```

---

**Trick**:

Put this in your `.htaccess`   file:

```
RewriteRule ^$  index.php?undone=/msj [QSA,L]
```

Edit your `index.php`  file and put this at the very first beginning:

```
    if(isset($_GET['undone'])){
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/abc/index.php' . $_GET['undone'];
        unset($_GET['undone']);

    }
```

Comment: OK, that's a good start. But I have this exact same rewrite rules on another server and that works... no suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: @pocketfullofcheese Another server? was that nginx?

Comment: what do you mean, redundant? Both are apache.

Comment: Edit your **index.php**  and put this at the beginning of the file: `var_dump($_SERVER);exit;`  . Put the output in your question!

Comment: Edit your rewrite rule to `RewriteRule ^$  index.php/msj [QSA,L,E=PATH_INFO:/msj] `. test it and tell me what happens!

Comment: @pocketfullofcheese How about `RewriteRule ^$ index.php?/msj [L]`?

Comment: That doesn't work. It doesn't give an error, but it also doesn't redirect (namely because that URL does not work with OJS).

Comment: One question: is this the only rule ? or there are other rules?

Comment: only rule. Only other thing in the file is "RewriteEngine On"