# Difficult problems with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a difficult problem:
In my .htaccess I have the following RewriteRules which do not function.

```
    RewriteRule u/(.*)/ user.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule u/(.*) user.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule user/(.*)/ user.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule user/(.*) user.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule view/(.*)/ view.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule view/(.*) view.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule show/(.*)/ show.php?img=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule show/(.*) show.php?img=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule report/(.*) report.php?img=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule report/(.*)/ report.php?img=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule search/tag/(.*) search.php?t=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule search/tag/(.*)/ search.php?t=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule search/(.*) search.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule search/(.*)/ search.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule bug/view/(.*)/ bug.php?view=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule bug/view/(.*) bug.php?view=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule bug/(.*) bug.php?step=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule bug/(.*)/ bug.php?step=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, when I enter a RewriteRule as

```
    RewriteRule ^ http://example.com [R, L]
```

I will be forwarded, so it works.

Solutions such as

```
    RewriteRule u/(.*)/ http://example.com/user.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

do not work. Also

```
    RewriteRule /u/(.*)/ user.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

or the like were not successful.

I have the problem since I recently moved to a new server. However, everything seems to be fine with the configuration.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What happens on the new server when you visit `domain.com/u/64/`? Do you get a "file not found" or do you get redirected to a different path?

Answer (score 1):

Did you search for a possible answer?

I found this:
[Why does this RewriteRule work with [R] but not with [QSA,L]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747063/why-does-this-rewriterule-work-with-r-but-not-with-qsa-l)

> It seems that:
>
> The FastCGI version when paired with Apache 2.2 doesn't seem to like
>   the rewriterule index.php/$1. Instead it prefers index.php?$1 but some
>   CMS don't like that. The CMS I am using does not like that. So
>   undone's comment to use ?$1 was on the right track, but because I had
>   no explanation, and the CMS I am using (Open Journal Systems) does not
>   work with the pathinfo stuff after a ?, then it was just not working.
>
> The solution was to change from FastCGI to just regular CGI.

check the other answers under that URL, they have valid points, that might help your case.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like you are using a wrong syntax. Try to put your pattern in double quotes and see if it works (remember: [the *pattern* in `RewriteRule` is a Regular Expression](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html)). Like this:

```
 RewriteRule "u/(.*)/" "http://example.com/user.php?u=$1" [L,QSA]
```

Or a better way is to enclose your patterns in: `^` (as start of string) and `$` (as end of string):

```
 RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ http://example.com/user.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That looks very wrong to me. I have never seen quote-wraps on expressions. Further, there is no need to use absolute URLs. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @MikeRockett Here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa Yes there is no obligation for absolute URLs in substitution argument but I tried to keep his original rules as much as possible.

Comment: Fascinating - didn't know you could do that... I could almost swear they were never used in the docs before... As for absolute URLs, one should only use them when there is benefit to do so.